# Stability order of Cr2+ ,Mn2+ , Fe2+ ,Co2+

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

Stability order is given as $\ce{Mn^2+ > Fe^2+ > Cr^2+> Co^2+}$

Of course I know that $\ce{Mn^2+}$ is the most stable form as it has half filled degenerate orbitals. But my query is regarding the stability of $\ce{Fe^2+}$ and $\ce{Cr^2+}$.

It is given in my book that $\ce{Fe^2+}$ has greater stability than $\ce{Cr^2+}$ through exchange energy. I want to know how exchange energy stabilizes $\ce{Fe^2+}$ more than $\ce{Cr^2+}$ .

Comment: What do you mean by stability here? Stability WRT reduction? Stability WRT oxidation? Stability of the complexes these ions form? Or something else?

Comment: @IanBush  it is a question from the medical entrance examination in India.

Comment: Well as given it is more or less meaningless

Comment: @IanBush it is not perfectly given in what terms the stability order is asked but they just asked the stability of M2+ ions. No specificity regarding this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Formation of ion takes place by removing electron from outermost shell.

Electronic configuration for Fe2+ is [Ar]3d6 4s0

Electronic configuration of Cr2+ is [Ar]3d4 4s0

Cr2+ is a stronger reducing agent that Fe2+ in aqueous solution(d3 configuration more stabls than d5 in aqueous solution).

So Cr2+ has higher tendency on losing electron compared to Fe2+ so Fe2+ is more stable than Cr2+.

Mn2+ has most stable and Co2+ is least stable(least exchange energy due to only 3 unpaired electrons).

Comment: You have read from here http://www.answers.com/Q/Why_is_d3_orbital_more_stable_in_water_than_d5 why d3 is more stable than d5 in water.